# Letter Class: Vertical Space Adjustment

Tags: letters

I have created a single file (`main.tex`) for a letter where I will add other TeX files (`letter_1.tex`) using `\input`. The document format is `letter` (for cover letters).

I would like to reduce the empty space above the starting line of the date.

I searched the forum for similar questions and tried using the `\vspace{}`, however, when I use `\vspace{}` I am getting overlaps in my text - specially at the `\opening{}` section. Kindly guide me to solve the problem.

```latex
%Code for the main file
\documentclass{letter} 

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\oddsidemargin=.2in
\evensidemargin=.2in
\textwidth=5.9in
\topmargin=-.5in
\textheight=9in

\begin{document}

\input{letter_1}

\end{document}
```

Code for the `letter_1.tex` file:

```latex
\begin{letter}{%
ABC,\\
XYZ, America %
}

\opening{Dear ABC}

My letter text here

\closing{Truly,

XYZ}

\end{letter}
```

Comment: You could make `\topmargin` more negative, or you could add vertical space to the end of your closing: `\closing{Truly,

XYZ\vspace*{3in}
}`.  There is probably a better way, however.

Comment: The ````\topmargin```` is working fine for reducing the empty white space on the top. My letter's closing is moving onto the next page, is there any way if I may bring it to the end of the first page? Even when I add 3 to 4 more lines of the text in my letter body, the first page gets the newly added text along with every other thing same. But still the closing gets to the start of the next page. I have checked the ````\vspace*{}```` in closing but its not making any difference.